# Could not install any app via Software in Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: gnome, 22.04

I am new with Ubuntu and after fresh installing Ubuntu 22.04 I noticed that I am not able to install any program via **Ubuntu Software**, then I installed the **Software (gnome-software)** and tried with it, but faced the same problem:

When I am opening the **Software** app and clicking on the any app to try install, after that the **Software** app closes automatically.

Then I tried to boot the **Software** app via terminal with the following command:
`gnome-software`

And reproduce the same steps with choosing any app and after I clicking on the app the terminal shows errors below:

```
12:52:12:0966 Gs  Only 0 apps for recent list, hiding
12:52:52:0967 Gs  not handling error failed for action get-popular: Get https://api.snapcraft.io/v2/snaps/find?architecture=amd64&category=featured&confinement=strict%2Cclassic&fields=base%2Cconfinement%2Ccontact%2Cdescription%2Cdownload%2Clicense%2Cprices%2Cprivate%2Cpublisher%2Crevision%2Csummary%2Ctitle%2Ctype%2Cversion%2Cwebsite%2Cstore-url%2Cmedia%2Ccommon-ids%2Cchannel: net/http: request canceled (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)
12:52:52:0969 Gs  adding wildcard app */*/*/org.gnome.Builder.desktop/* to plugin cache
12:52:52:0969 Gs  adding wildcard app */*/*/org.gnome.Calculator.desktop/* to plugin cache
12:52:52:0969 Gs  adding wildcard app */*/*/org.gnome.clocks.desktop/* to plugin cache
12:52:52:0969 Gs  adding wildcard app */*/*/org.gnome.Dictionary.desktop/* to plugin cache
12:52:52:0969 Gs  adding wildcard app */*/*/org.gnome.Documents.desktop/* to plugin cache
12:52:52:0969 Gs  adding wildcard app */*/*/org.gnome.Evince/* to plugin cache
12:52:52:0969 Gs  adding wildcard app */*/*/org.gnome.gedit.desktop/* to plugin cache
12:52:52:0969 Gs  adding wildcard app */*/*/org.gnome.Maps.desktop/* to plugin cache
12:52:52:0969 Gs  adding wildcard app */*/*/org.gnome.Weather/* to plugin cache
12:52:53:0437 GsPluginSnap Failed to find refreshable snaps: status-code=500 kind=(null) message=cannot list updates: Post https://api.snapcraft.io/v2/snaps/refresh: net/http: request canceled (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)
12:52:53:0516 Gs  Only 7 apps for popular list, hiding
12:52:53:0595 Gtk Could not load a pixbuf from icon theme.
This may indicate that pixbuf loaders or the mime database could not be found.
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

I tried to update & upgrade packages, reinstall gnome-software and it still closes, please help me to solve this problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Snapcraft, which Ubuntu Software uses in the background, is experiencing intermittent outages today due to a firewall issue on their part. You can see how it got HTTP 500 errors (server error) when trying to access `api.snapcraft.io`.

There is nothing you can do, since the issue is with their servers. It should be back up-and-running soon (hopefully).

Answer (score 0):

Run the following commands:

```
rm ~/.local/share/gnome-software/*
sudo apt-get upgrade gnome-software
sudo apt-get update
```

This will solve the problem i hope.

Please comment if this worked for you.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your reply, but this does not help:

`rm ~/.local/share/gnome-software/*
rm: cannot remove '/home/{user}/.local/share/gnome-software/*': No such file or directory`, I already tried update & upgrade commands they did not help too...

Comment: Does gnome-software display apps?

Comment: Yes it does, and when I am clicking on any app it automatically closes